# Input error recognized just first time, second time it starts to run

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

When I'm trying to select a wrong choice it gave me the error the first time. Second time it starts to run the "Select level" block. For example if I input choice "12", the program returns the error and put me to select again and this time I input "13" it returns the "Select level" block. I need to put a while or what there to verify the choice ever time?

```
import random
import sys

choice = None

while choice != "0":
     print('''
     --------------------
     Welcome to Hangman
     --------------------

     Please select a menu option:

     0 - Exit
     1 - Enter a new text file to be read:
     2 - Play Game

     ''')

choice= input("Enter you choice: ")

if choice == "0":
    sys.exit("Exiting from Python")

elif choice =="1":
    while True:
        try:
            fileInput = input("Enter a new text file name: ")
            List = open(fileInput).readlines()
            break
        except:
            print ("\n Failed to open the file")
            sys.exit()

elif choice == "2":
    List = open("words_for_hangman.txt").readlines()

elif choice == " ":
    choice = print("\n That is not a valit option! Please try again!")
    choice = input("Choice:")

else:
    choice = print("\n That is not a valid option! Please try again!")
    choice = input("Choice: ")

print('''

Now select your difficulty level:

0 - EASY
1 - INTERMEDIATE
2 - HARD

''')

level= input("Enter your choice: ")
if level == "0":
    word = random.choice(List)
    word = word.strip()
    hidden_word = "*" * len(word)
    lives = 10
    guessed = []
elif level == "1":
    word = random.choice(List)
    word = word.strip()
    hidden_word = "*" * len(word)
    lives = 7
    guessed = []
elif level == "2":
    word = random.choice(List)
    word = word.strip()
    hidden_word = "*" * len(word)
    lives = 5
    guessed = []


while lives != 0 and hidden_word != word:
    print("\n-------------------------------")
    print("The word is")
    print(hidden_word.replace("_"," _ "))
    print("\nThere are", len(word), "letters in this word")
    print("So far the letters you have guessed are: ")
    print(' '.join(guessed))
    print("\n You have", lives,"lives remaining")
    guess = input("\n Guess a letter: \n")
    guess = guess.upper()
    if len(guess) > 1:
        guess = input("\n You can only guess one letter at a time!\n Try again: ")
        guess = guess.upper()
    elif guess== " ":
        guess = input("\n You need to input a letter, not a space!\n Come on let's try again: ")
        guess = guess.upper()
    while guess in guessed:
        print("\n You have already guessed that letter!")
        guess = input("\n Please take another guess: ")
        guess = guess.upper()
    guessed.append(guess)
    if guess in word:
        print('''-------------------------------
        ''')
        print("Well done!", guess.upper(),"is in the word")
        word_so_far = ""
        for i in range (len(word)):
            if guess == str(word[i]):
                word_so_far += guess
            else:
                word_so_far += hidden_word[i]
        hidden_word = word_so_far
    else:
        print('''-------------------------------
        ''')
        print("Sorry, but", guess, "is not in the word")
        lives -= 1

if lives == 0:
    print("GAME OVER! You have no lives left")
else:
    print("\n CONGRATULATIONS! You have guessed the word")
    print("The word was", word)
    print("\nThank you for playing Hangman")
```

Comment: Your mistake is that when the user input is wrong you take a new input which might be wrong again. But you dont check that. A good way to get out of this is to resume the loop when user choice is wrong. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're second input isn't actually getting checked. You need to place it in a while loop so that it always go back to the same input and does all the checks again:

```
goodChoice = false
while not goodChoice:
    #print text message
    choice = input("Enter you choice: ")
    if choice == 1:
        goodchoice = True

#game code
```

The above (without your functions) will happen forever until a choice that is 1 is entered, it will then go down to the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

you need to continue the loop so next input can be taken from user, when the input is wrong.

```
if choice == "0":
    sys.exit("Exiting from Python")

elif choice =="1":
    while True:
        try:
            fileInput = input("Enter a new text file name: ")
            List = open(fileInput).readlines()
            break
        except:
            print ("\n Failed to open the file")
            sys.exit()

elif choice == "2":
    List = open("words_for_hangman.txt").readlines()

elif choice == " ":
    choice = print("\n That is not a valit option! Please try again!")
    # continue the loop if the choice is wrong
    continue

else:
    choice = print("\n That is not a valid option! Please try again!")
    # continue the loop if the choice is wrong
    continue
```